# how to add drop down menu to the right button of navigatorIOS in react native

Tags: react-native

In react native, I am using NavigatorIOS and they already are providing the parameters named onRightButtonPress, rightButtonTitle. But, I don't know how to add [the dropdown menu](https://github.com/alinz/react-native-dropdown) in it.

Comment: same question to me